# React Redux-a child component does not re-render on state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

The architecture is like this: I have a `plotMap` component, which gets a list of plots from state and maps them to a bunch of `plotMarker` components, which return polygons/markers, based on map zoom (also read from state). If a given plot is selected for editing, the `plotMarker` component returns a `plotPolygon` component which is editable. When a user saves the edited `plotPolygon` component, this updates the corresponding plot in the state plot list.

Problem: the `plotMarker`'s polygon, which is displayed as soon as the edited `plotPolygon` component is successfully saved, is not updated with the new shape, but keeps the old. Only when one zooms out, and the `plotMarker` renders its marker component, and zooms back in, and the `plotMarker` renders its polygon component again, is the new shape displayed.

Could this be due to a lag inside the app? How can I make the `plotMarker` display the new polygon as soon as it is successfully saved?

**plotMap component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../../actions';
import { Map, TileLayer, LayersControl, MapControl } from 'react-leaflet';
import { GoogleLayer } from './GoogleLayer';
import { geolocated } from 'react-geolocated';
import 'leaflet-geocoder-mapzen';
import SearchBox from './searchBox';
import Control from 'react-leaflet-control';
import { centroid } from '@turf/turf';
import PlotMarker from './plotMarker';

const { BaseLayer } = LayersControl;
const key = 'key';
const hybrid = 'HYBRID';
const terrain = 'TERRAIN';
const road = 'ROADMAP';
const satellite = 'SATELLITE';

const centerLat = props => {
    if (
        props.isGeolocationAvailable &&
        props.isGeolocationEnabled &&
        props.coords
    ) {
        return props.coords.latitude;
    }
    return 32.11;
};

const centerLong = props => {
    if (
        props.isGeolocationAvailable &&
        props.isGeolocationEnabled &&
        props.coords
    ) {
        return props.coords.longitude;
    }
    return 34.963;
};

const mapCenterPoint = props => {
    if (props.plots && (props.selectedPlot || props.plotBeingEdited)) {
        let ourPlot = props.plots.filter(
            plot => plot._id === (props.selectedPlot || props.plotBeingEdited)
        )[0];
        try {
            let center = centroid(ourPlot.feature).geometry.coordinates.reverse();
            return { center: center, zoom: 16 };
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
    return { center: [centerLat(props), centerLong(props)], zoom: 8 };
};

export class PlotMap extends Component {
    markers = props => {
        if (props.plots) {
            return (
                <div>
                    {(props.filteredPlots || props.plots).map(
                        plot =>
                            plot &&
                            plot.feature &&
                            plot._id && (
                                <PlotMarker
                                    key={plot._id}
                                    id={plot._id}
                                    name={plot.name}
                                    geoJSON={plot.feature}
                                />
                            )
                    )}
                </div>
            );
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div
                className="col-sm-8 m-auto p-0 flex-column float-right"
                style={{ height: `85vh` }}>
                <Map
                    center={mapCenterPoint(this.props).center}
                    zoom={mapCenterPoint(this.props).zoom}
                    zoomControl={true}
                    onZoomend={e => {
                        this.props.setZoomLevel(e.target.getZoom());
                    }}
                    onMoveEnd={e => {
                        this.props.setMapCenter(e.target.getCenter());
                    }}>
                    <LayersControl position="topright">
                        <BaseLayer name="Google Maps Roads">
                            <GoogleLayer googlekey={key} maptype={road} />
                        </BaseLayer>
                        <BaseLayer name="Google Maps Terrain">
                            <GoogleLayer googlekey={key} maptype={terrain} />
                        </BaseLayer>
                        <BaseLayer checked name="Google Maps Hybrid">
                            <GoogleLayer
                                googlekey={key}
                                maptype={hybrid}
                                libraries={['geometry', 'places']}
                            />
                        </BaseLayer>
                    </LayersControl>
                    <SearchBox postion="bottomright" />
                    {this.markers(this.props)}
                </Map>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        filteredPlots: state.plots.filteredPlots,
        plots: state.plots.plots,
        selectedPlot: state.plots.selectedPlot,
        mapCenter: state.plots.mapCenter
    };
}

export default geolocated({
    positionOptions: {
        enableHighAccuracy: false
    },
    userDecisionTimeout: 5000,
    suppressLocationOnMount: false
})(connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(PlotMap));
```

**plotMarker component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../../actions';
import { Marker, Popup, GeoJSON } from 'react-leaflet';
import { centroid } from '@turf/turf';
import PlotPolygon from './plotPolygon';

const position = geoJSON => {
    return centroid(geoJSON).geometry.coordinates.reverse();
};

export class PlotMarker extends Component {
    render() {
        const {
            id,
            name,
            geoJSON,
            zoomLevel,
            selectedPlot,
            plotBeingEdited
        } = this.props;
        const markerPosition = position(geoJSON);
        let style = () => {
            return {
                color: 'blue'
            };
        };
        if (selectedPlot === id) {
            style = () => {
                return {
                    color: 'red'
                };
            };
        }
        if (zoomLevel > 14 && plotBeingEdited === id) {
            return <PlotPolygon id={id} geoJSON={geoJSON} />;
        } else if (zoomLevel > 14) {
            return (
                <GeoJSON
                    id={id}
                    data={geoJSON}
                    style={style}
                    onClick={() => {
                        this.props.selectPlot(id);
                    }}
                />
            );
        }
        return (
            <Marker
                id={id}
                className="marker"
                position={markerPosition}
                onClick={() => {
                    this.props.selectPlot(id);
                }}>
                <Popup>
                    <span>{name}</span>
                </Popup>
            </Marker>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        selectedPlot: state.plots.selectedPlot,
        plotBeingEdited: state.plots.plotBeingEdited,
        zoomLevel: state.plots.zoomLevel,
        plots: state.plots.plots,
        filteredPlots: state.plots.filteredPlots
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(PlotMarker);
```

**plotPolygon component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../../actions';
import { Polygon, FeatureGroup } from 'react-leaflet';
import { EditControl } from 'react-leaflet-draw';

const positions = props => {
    return props.geoJSON.geometry.coordinates[0].map(a => [a[1], a[0]]);
};

export class PlotPolygon extends Component {
    render() {
        const { id, geoJSON } = this.props;
        return (
            <FeatureGroup>
                <EditControl
                    position="topright"
                    onEdited={e => {
                        e.layers.eachLayer(a => {
                            this.props.updatePlot({
                                id: id,
                                feature: a.toGeoJSON()
                            });
                        });
                    }}
                    edit={{ remove: false }}
                    draw={{
                        marker: false,
                        circle: false,
                        rectangle: false,
                        polygon: false,
                        polyline: false
                    }}
                />
                <Polygon positions={[positions(this.props)]} />;
            </FeatureGroup>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { plots: state.plots.plots, filteredPlots: state.plots.filteredPlots };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(PlotPolygon);
```

Comment: Do you need to reset your zoom level after you exit the edit mode? Your logic is very tightly coupled between `mapCenterPoint` and the `if(zoomLevel...` portion of plotMarker. I'm wondering if you may have a state that is causing this to always evaluate true after editing (and until manually zooming): `props.plots && (props.selectedPlot || props.plotBeingEdited)`

Comment: Yeah, that works. I have to figure out a more elegant way of doing it than the hacky way I came up with (dispatching a zoom level of 13, then of 15, immediately after save success in the action,) but it works. Can you put the comment as an answer, and I'll accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Original Solution:

Do you need to reset your zoom level after you exit the edit mode? Your logic is very tightly coupled between `mapCenterPoint` and the `if(zoomLevel...` portion of `plotMarker`. I'm wondering if you may have a state that is causing this to always evaluate true after editing (and until manually zooming): `props.plots && (props.selectedPlot || props.plotBeingEdited)`

---

## Thoughts on Refactoring:

> to figure out a more elegant way

### Option 1: HOCs

Higher Order Components (or HOCs) might be a great approach for this. You have an example of a HOC already in your code:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(PlotMarker);
```

HOCs are really just functions that return something useful to you in the React world. As such, they're a great form of code reuse. `connect` is a HOC that returns a function in this scenario, but HOCs are often used to return components. So you may have a HOC like `plotMarker(zoomLevel, beingEdited)` that performs the logic itself to determine which type of marker component to render.

#### Check out [React's Higher Order Component Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) for more.

---

### Option 2: Single Return Statement

I've always been a fan of using a single return statement for the render method. I haven't dug in super deep to how React handles diffs, but I'm pretty sure from my experience that it responds better this way - so it might remove the need for you to twitch the zoom levels to reset it.

#### How I would perform all of `PlotMarker`'s logic inside one return:

```
export class PlotMarker extends Component{
  render(){
    const {
      id,
      name,
      geoJSON,
      zoomLevel,
      selectedPlot,
      plotBeingEdited
    } = this.props;

    const markerPosition = position(geoJSON);

    let style = () =>{
      return {
        color: 'blue'
      };
    };
    if(selectedPlot === id){
      style = () =>{
        return {
          color: 'red'
        };
      };
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {
          zoomLevel > 14 && plotBeingEdited === id &&
          <PlotPolygon id={id} geoJSON={geoJSON}/> ||
          
          zoomLevel > 14 &&
          <GeoJSON
            id={id}
            data={geoJSON}
            style={style}
            onClick={() =>{
              this.props.selectPlot(id);
            }}
          /> ||
          
          <Marker
            id={id}
            className="marker"
            position={markerPosition}
            onClick={() => {
              this.props.selectPlot(id);
            }}>
            <Popup>
              <span>{name}</span>
            </Popup>
          </Marker>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```